# CentOS as Printer Server

Tags: centos, printer

I have a network setup of 1x CentOS as Server and 10x Fedora as Workstations, the printer is connected to CentOS's USB port. I want this printer to print directly from fedora workstations and also would like to monitor the printer usage like no. of pages requested from different workstations and alike. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you though about setting up a CUPS server.  This should give you the function you need.  I'm not 100% on the full reporting of CUPS but I believe it will do the function you listed above.